# Streaming video to two sites makes my processor 100%

Tags: video, streaming, video-streaming, virtual-webcam

I have Compaq Presario CQ56-172SR Laptop and Camera Trust Trino HD 18679(720p)

When i stream video to one site (for example twitchtv) will best quality everything is normal.

But when i stream to two sites i get my processor to 100% and its start lagging/freezing.

i use Splitcam and Manycams for the camera virtualization. use latest flash player and google chrome. OS - Win XP x64

So i wanted to ask is there any Camera virtualization software which uses less processing power or is there different solution/tricks when streming to two sites. i thought about increasing virtual memory? will this help? Any suggestions?

Comment: Just throwing this out there, not meant as an answer, but it sounds like a potential multithreading/GPU-CPU bottleneck issue. I looked up the [specs](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02540074&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en) to your laptop, emphasizing on your CPU 'Intel Celeron Processor T3500' and GPU 'Intel GMA 4500M' I'm amazed you got it to stream one HD feed. Combined with WinXP 64, which was almost as bad as Vista for driver support, it's fairly clear what you must do. As far as quick fix goes... I would go into services and shut down processes you don't need running.

Comment: if you mean changing the OS i was before with Win7(x64) and it was worse. was barely streaming. so no virtualization techiques will help?
i thought something like ip camera virtualization will that posibly help? as the stream will be accessible from one place.
also what are theese external encoding hardware? are they cheap?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not the best source for answering questions on webcams and video encoding. I can tell you that Video compression/encoding is very CPU intensive, and the higher the resolution, the more GPU memory is required. Moving from Win7 to XP may have helped, because XP has less background processes and freed up more resources. Try running msconfig.exe from the run box, startup tab, and remove those startup programs you don't need constantly running. This may free up enough resources for you to stream to both locations. Outside of that heavyd's answer is the correct one, in my opinion.

Comment: Virtualization is just going to make your problem worse, you really need to encode once and then send that encoded video to two different places, see me update below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encoding video is a very CPU intensive process (not memory intensive, so changing memory will not help).  Your computer is running relatively slow processor (2.0Ghz Celeron), so its not surprising that it can only handle one stream at a time, especially if you're using HD video.

To fix the problem you could look into external hardware to encode your video, or into a more powerful computer.  Another option would be to decrease the quality of the video (maybe drop down to just 480p instead of 720p).

#### Update:

After thinking about your problem for a sec, what you really want to do is have a single application encode the video, and then stream the encoded video to two different streaming services.  This should be possible if your machine is able to stream to one without problems.  I'm not familiar with how streaming websites accept streaming data, so I can't help you with implementing it, but something like [VLC](http://videolan.org) which can output to multiple sources might do the trick.